# How to validate 100's of columns in Azure DataFactory data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow which needs to validate 200+ columns in Azure Data Factory. My source file is Excel and I am using 'Assert' to validate the columns. When I gave 5 columns to validate in assert, I am able to preview data in debug mode. But when I used all the 200+ columns validations, it just shows 'Fetching Data' and then timeouts. Can someone please help how to achieve this quick.
I have published the flow and tried to execute it on 16 cores Integration runtime. Still it is of no use. I terminated the flow after waiting for 30 minutes. The size of my data set is quite small around 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found this official MS doc documenting the similar scenario [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#timeout-or-slow-performance-when-parsing-large-excel-file), see if this helps.

In excel source dataset, use range (for example, A1:G100) + firstRowAsHeader=false, and then it can load data from all Excel files even though the column name and count is different.

> #### Timeout or slow performance when parsing large Excel file
>
> - **Symptoms**:
>
>   - When you create Excel dataset and import schema from connection/store, preview data, list, or refresh worksheets, you may
>     hit timeout error if the excel file is large in size.
>   - When you use copy activity to copy data from large Excel file (>= 100 MB) into other data store, you may experience slow performance
>     or OOM issue.
> - **Cause**:
>
>   - For operations like importing schema, previewing data, and listing worksheets on excel dataset, the timeout is 100 s and static.
>     For large Excel file, these operations may not finish within the
>     timeout value.
>   - The copy activity reads the whole Excel file into memory then locate the specified worksheet and cells to read data. This behavior
>     is due to the underlying SDK the service uses.
> - **Resolution**:
>
>   - For importing schema, you can generate a smaller sample file, which is a subset of original file, and choose "import schema from
>     sample file" instead of "import schema from connection/store".
>   - For listing worksheet, in the worksheet dropdown, you can click "Edit" and input the sheet name/index instead.
>   - To copy large excel file (>100 MB) into other store, you can use Data Flow Excel source which sport streaming read and perform
>     better.